# Find all numbers in a collection that are divisible by the numbers of another collection

Tags: c#

My task is to find which integers from a collection are divisible to other integers in another collection. I'm trying to solve this using predicates and functions but I'm a bit stuck. Why is this not working?

```
Func<List<int>, List<int>, List<int>> func = (x, y) => x.Where(n => y.All(m => m % n == 0)).ToList();
```

I need to return a list of integers

Comment: Divisible by any or each?

Answer (score 3):

You have swapped `n` and `m` in your check, so you are returning all values (`n`) in `x` where all values in `y` are divisible by `n`. You could give your variables better names to help prevent these errors:

```
Func<List<int>, List<int>, List<int>> func = 
    (dividends, divisors) => dividends.Where( 
         dividend => divisors.All(divisor => dividend % divisor == 0)
    ).ToList();
```